# can't download zip file has content in joomla! extension

Tags: php, joomla, download, zip

I developed extension download zip file for joomla! 3.8. I have create the zip file and add some text file in it. I want to download it by browser but i can't. Please help me!
My code:

```
$zipName = 'test.zip';
  $zip = new ZipArchive;
  $zip->open($zipName,  ZipArchive::CREATE);
  for($i = 0; $i < count($datas); $i++){
      switch (strtoupper($filetype)){
          case 'XLIFF':
              $filenames[$i] = $filenames[$i].".xlf";
              //create xliff file to add in zip file.
              $this->createXLIFF($datas[$i], $header, $deduplicate, $sourcelanguage, $targetlanguage, $filenames[$i]);
              $zip->addFile(realpath($filenames[$i]),$filenames[$i]);
              break;
      }
  }
  $zip->close();
  @header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
  @header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
  @header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
  @header("Content-Type: application/download");
  @header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$zipName."\"");
  @header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  @header("Pragma: public");
  @header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  @header("Content-Length: ".filesize($zipName));
  flush();
  readfile($zipName);
  unlink($zipName);
  foreach ($filenames as $filename){
      unlink($filename);
  }
  exit;
```

and output:
[output in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXe59.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't"?

Comment: I can't download it. Content of zip file will show on browser as attached image!

Comment: Why do you suppress possible errors from `header()` calls? Maybe, they point you to a solution. And why are you sending mutliple `Content-Type` headers?

Comment: I sending multiple Content-Type headers to force download. I used @ annotation to prevent warning from header().

Comment: There cannot be multiple `Content-Type` headers. And if something is not working as expected, don't ignore warnings

Comment: Try removing all `Content-Type` headers except the one with `application/octet-stream`

Comment: I try only one with "application/octet-stream" but result not change

Comment: I try download with the empty zip file  and it's ok . But with zip file has content, I can't download it and the content will be show on browser